# $\forall x\in A(\in\mathcal P(E)),\,P(x)\Leftrightarrow\forall x\in E,\,(x\in A)\wedge P(x)$?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

The question is in the title.

When I am working in $\mathcal P(E)$, do statements like $\forall x\in A,\,P(x)$ translate to $\forall x\in E,\,(x\in A)\wedge P(x)$ or to $\forall x\in E,\,(x\in A)\implies P(x)$?

Comment: At the title's beginining, did you mean this instead: $\forall x\in A(\subset E),\,P(x)?$

Comment: @ryang thank you! it should have been $\in$.

Comment: @ryang $\mathcal P(E)$ is the set of all subsets of $E$.

Comment: Oh, power set. Why not just say subset of E instead of element of E's power set.

Comment: @ryang the notes that i am using usually employ $\mathcal P(E),\,(\mathcal P(E))^2$ etc ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there is difference between existential ($\exists x$) and "for all" ($\forall x$) quantification:

$\forall x\big (x\in A\Rightarrow P(x)\big)$ is different than $\exists x\big(x\in A \wedge P(x)\big)$.

Comment: makes sense. thank you very much!

Comment: You never actually justify that they are different, @Wuestenfux